# Generate random value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby. I would like to generate random value and add to domain name. What is the proper way to do this in Ruby?

```
:domain => 'test-domain'
```

For example I would like to do something like this:

```
:domain => "test-domain #{SecureRandom.random_number(100)}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want it to be in `100` numbers, use simple `rand` function.

You can use simple `rand` function of ruby.

`rand` takes parameters to get the random numbers from that range.

It generally takes 2 params,  **`rand(from, to)`**, wehere from defaults to 0.

**So, `rand(0,100)` starts from 0 till 100**

**`rand(10,20)` gives values b/w 10 and 20**

```
"test-domain #{rand(100)}"

==> "test-domain 46"

"test-domain #{rand(500)}"

==> "test-domain 246"

"test-domain #{rand(1000)}"

==> "test-domain 786"
```

[**RUBY HAS A RANDOM CLASS OF ITS OWN**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html)

**For random characters,**

You can use, **`(0...5).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join`**. 
(from outer source)

In place of **`(0...5)`** you can take the number of characters you prefer.

**Example Upper Case:**

```
"test-domain #{(0...5).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join}"
 => "test-domain UKONO"

 "test-domain #{(0...3).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join}"
 => "test-domain OFU"

 "test-domain #{(0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join}"
 => "test-domain YHODHUSY"
```

**For lowercase:**

```
"test-domain #{(0...8).map { (97 + rand(26)).chr }.join}"
 => "test-domain vozxaxza"

"test-domain #{(0...4).map { (97 + rand(26)).chr }.join}"
 => "test-domain ygpm"
```

Comment: Can you show me example with characters only, please?

Comment: replace 65 with 97, updating the answer please check

Comment: @PeterPenzov, any further help needed?